# modify ip and port where modoboa is listening

Tags: python, django

How can I modify IP and port where modoboa is listening. Default its listening on localhost and port 8000

```
http://localhost:8000/
```

I like to make it listening on any ip, something like

```
http://0.0.0.0:8000/
```

I can't find no place in the docu describing this.
thanks in advance

b.t.w. : I am not able to create a new tag "modoboa", maybe someone with 1500 points can do it for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The web-facing part of modoboa seems to be just an ordinary django application. You can specify the address you're binding to like this:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Please note that the documentation advises against using the embedded webserver in production. It [recommends you to use an external webserver like Apache or nginx instead](https://modoboa.readthedocs.org/en/latest/integration/web_servers.html).

Comment: I promise not to use the embedded server in production.